# How to display validation message from fluentapi mapping in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Fluent api mapping:

```
 internal class ProjectMap :EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
    {
            public ProjectMap()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.ProjectId);

            Property(p => p.ProjectId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            Property(p => p.StartDate < p.ExpectedEndDate);

            ToTable(TableSettings.Projects, TableSettings.DefaultSchema);
        }
    }
```

Here i want to show error message on startdate property..So how can i show it on client side view?